# Book: “Magento Extension Development v1.0”, unable to display “Hello World”

Tags: magento

I am following 2 books: Getting Started with Magento Extension Development. and the official “Magento Extension Development v1.0”. 
And I'm unable to make my extension echoing "Hello World".

I believed there are 3 area I need to take care, in order to echo "Hello World":

1. activate the module from `app/etc/modules/Froggyline_HappyHour.xml`.
2. Setup module config  `app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Froggyline_HappyHour>
               <version>0.0.0</version>
           </Froggyline_HappyHour>
       </modules>
       <frontend>
           <routers>
               <froggyline_happyhour>
                   <use>standard</use>
                   <args>
                       <module>Froggyline_HappyHour</module>
                       <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
                   </args>
               </froggyline_happyhour>
           </routers>
       </frontend>
   </config>
   ```
3. add `app/code/community/Froggyline/HappyHour/controller/GreetingController.php`

   ```
   <?php
   class Froggyline_HappyHour_GreetingController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function helloWorldAction()
       {
           echo 'Hello World';
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

I am visiting the following URL: `http://localhost/happyhour/greeting/helloWorld` and receive `Http 404`.

Which step did I miss, so that the page will display "Hello World"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [extension development v1.0](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf) has a typo: `controller` supposed to be `controllers`. Just wasted my day. :(

Credit goes to https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/68567/26421